# Plone: How to apply a mixin class to the standard ATFolder class

Tags: plone, plone-4.x, archetypes

I have a `getThumbnailPath` method for my custom Archetypes-based content objects; it chooses the preview image, puts a scaled copy to the file system (if not already up-to-date), and returns something like `/++thumbnails++/<image uid>.jpg` to have the thumbnail images served by Apache. With the result stored as a metadata field in my catalog for list views, this should be pretty efficient: all checking and scaling is only done when the metadata is recalculated, and for standard access no Python thread is involved.

However, I do need preview images for some folders as well (using the first `MyImage` object in that folder, for example). I could monkey-patch a special version of my method to `ATFolder`, but it would probably be cleaner to inject my mixin class. Is this possible?

**Update:**
Ulrich Schwarz pointed me to the possibility to use adapters and interfaces (one each, perhaps?). Based on this, my current idea would be:

- Have an interface class `IThumbnailable` which is *implemented* by my custom types, and by `ATFolder`. It provides the `getThumbnailPath` method, and perhaps supporting data.
- Have an adapter, perhaps called `thumbnail`, which likely provides the implementation of the `getThumbnailPath` method(s).

**Thumbnail choice logic**

For my own content types, I was able to implement the following, based on a small hierarchy of mixin classes:

1. If the schema of the object contains an `image` field, and if it is non-empty, use this image: store a scaled version of it to the filesystem and return a path to access it.
2. Otherwise, if the object's method `getRawText` returns text which contains an `<img>` object whose `src` attribute refers to an object by `uid`, find this object and return the result of its `getThumbnailPath` method.

For folders, I'd like to have (currently done by monkey-patching):

3. If the folder contains images as direct children (`MyImage` objects), use the first one (catalog search, `'sort_on': 'getObjPositionInParent'`) and return the result of its `getThumbnailPath` method.
4. If the folder has a *standard page*, use the `getRawText` of that page.

Back to the mixin classes:

5. If nothing else worked, return the path to a standard thumbnail for the current type.

Thus, for the final solution I'd need to think whether I should maintain my little hierarchy or inspect every single object.

Comment: [Adapters](https://docs.plone.org/4/en/appendices/five-grok/core-components/adapters.html) to the rescue? Your functionality would live in a separate interface `IThumbnailable`, and you can provide code that allows you to cast both ATFolders and your custom type to `IThumbnailable`.

Comment: This might be the way to go, thank you. I'll need to work this out; probably I'll update my question ...

Comment: Hope I got your reqs right, not sure where exactly you want to display the thumbnails, but to create a dedicated thumbnail, you could use collective.contentleadimage, to extend folders with an image-field. If you want to show the first image living within a folder, put a little logic to the template, using a browser-view.

Comment: @IdaEbkes: I use the thumbnails for several carousel views, and for list views. Those are used frequently on my site, and the content should come entirely from the catalog data; a nice side effect is that now all of those thumbnails are served by Apache directly.
Currently, my monkeypatch-based solution works ok; however, I try to eliminate those somewhat hackish solutions.

Comment: I posted a link to your question here https://community.plone.org/t/stack-overflow-plone-how-to-apply-a-mixin-class-to-the-standard-atfolder-class/4244